# Prevent nginx to execute images as PHP script

Tags: nginx, php, hacking

My website has been compromized by an user who uploaded an image with PHP code in it. This code allows to upload files, and he uploaded a malicious PHP script.

He was able to call his "image-php" with a GET on this URL :

```
http://mypwnedwebsite.com/image.jpg/.php
```

How can I configure nginx to prevent this behaviour? I mean, with a simple `/.php`, it acts as everything was PHP, which is wrong from my point of view.

I actually have a "classical" nginx 1.6.2 configuration, and I think this part is the most relevant :

```
location ~ \.php$
    {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: See [this article](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php). You are missing a `try_files $uri =404;` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
location ~ \.php$
    {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /404.html;
    }
```

It tries to find $uri, if not a folder, if not 404 error is thrown.

Comment: Thank you, it actually works. Do I have to put `try_files $uri $uri/ /404.html` in every `location` block on every website, or is there a way to do this globally?

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/ 
The try_files directive

Like the return and rewrite directives, the try_files directive is placed in a server or location block. As parameters, it takes a list of one or more files and directories and a final URI:

try_files file … uri;